# emberjs: Testing with Pavlov/QUnit produces TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getHandler'

Tags: ember.js

Warning: I am a newbie. Thanks in advance for any help.

Pavlov/QUnit is causing problems with the router in my ember app. When using QUnit alone, the following test passes:

```
test "/contacts", ->
  expect(1)
  visit('/contacts').then ->
    ok(exists(".nav"), "The navbar was rendered")
```

But when using Pavlov with QUnit, the following test dies:

```
describe 'contacts index', ->
    it 'does render index', ->
      visit('/contacts').then ->
        assert(exists(".nav")).isTrue('The navbar was rendered')
```

and produces a "has no method 'getHandler'" error in the collectObjects method when the following is executed:

> var handler = router.getHandler(result.handler);

Stack trace is below:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getHandler'
    at collectObjects (http://localhost:3000/assets/test_helper.js:37674:28)
    at Object.Router.handleURL (http://localhost:3000/assets/test_helper.js:37347:9)
    at Ember.Router.Ember.Object.extend.handleURL (http://localhost:3000/assets/test_helper.js:38135:17)
    at Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.handleURL (http://localhost:3000/assets/test_helper.js:41451:12)
    at http://localhost:3000/assets/test_helper.js:18367:19
    at Object.Ember.handleErrors (http://localhost:3000/assets/test_helper.js:14228:17)
    at invoke (http://localhost:3000/assets/test_helper.js:18365:16)
    at Object.tryable (http://localhost:3000/assets/test_helper.js:18550:14)
    at Object.Ember.tryFinally (http://localhost:3000/assets/test_helper.js:15023:24)
    at Object.Ember.run (http://localhost:3000/assets/test_helper.js:18554:16)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same problem with QUnit. The tests were starting before my Ember application was ready, so calls to `visit()` would fail.

Try turning the QUnit autostart flag to false (http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.config/) and call `QUnit.start()` from your application ready callback. That fixed it for me, if you need more help you can look at this repo: https://github.com/remichaignon/ember-boilerplate

Answer (score 3):

Set up the Ember-testing/QUnit tests like this:

```
App.setupForTesting();
App.injectTestHelpers();

module("Integration Tests", {
  setup: function() {
    App.reset();
    Ember.run(App, App.advanceReadiness);
  }
});
```

Of course, replace `App` with your app's name.

The new [Testing guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/integration/) currently suggests this, but does not show the code.