# Ember.js & QUnit : "TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getHandler'" when calling visit

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm getting an error when using visit in a test :

**TypeError: Object # has no method 'getHandler'**

```
module("visit", {
  setup: function() {
    Ember.run(App, App.advanceReadiness);
  },
  teardown: function() {
    App.reset();
  }
});

test("visit works", function () {
  expect(2);

  // this gets executed
  equal(1, 1);

  return visit("/").then(function() {
    // this doesn't
    equal(1, 1);
  });
});
```

The resulting error trace is :

```
Died on test #2     at eval (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066)), <anonymous>:10:1)
    at eval (native)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066), <anonymous>:2:14066)
    at Function.p.extend.globalEval (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066), <anonymous>:2:14077)
    at p.ajaxSetup.converters.text script (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066), <anonymous>:2:83767)
    at cC (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066), <anonymous>:2:5874)
    at y (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066), <anonymous>:2:79888)
    at d (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066), <anonymous>:2:85578): Object #<Object> has no method 'getHandler'
Source:     
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getHandler'
    at generateHandlerInfos (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066)), <anonymous>:25824:31)
    at performTransition (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066)), <anonymous>:25758:30)
    at createURLTransition (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066)), <anonymous>:25501:18)
    at doTransition (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066)), <anonymous>:26067:20)
    at Object.Router.handleURL (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066)), <anonymous>:25213:20)
    at Ember.Router.Ember.Object.extend._doTransition (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066)), <anonymous>:26491:53)
    at Ember.Router.Ember.Object.extend.handleURL (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066)), <anonymous>:26331:21)
    at Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.handleURL (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066)), <anonymous>:30240:16)
    at Object.Backburner.run (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066)), <anonymous>:4862:30)
    at Object.Ember.run (eval at <anonymous> (eval at <anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:3000/javascripts/libs/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js:2:14066)), <anonymous>:5200:30)
```

I've made sure Ember is loaded before the tests are run as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16759633/emberjs-testing-with-pavlov-qunit-produces-typeerror-object-object-has-no-m?answertab=active#tab-top). QUnit is also working properly as a basic test on fixtures is working.

I've now spent hours on this issue and I don't have any clue why this is happening.

**Edit (following Daniel's comment)**
The route is pretty simple and looks like that :

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function(){
    this.transitionTo('about');
  }
});
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.route('about');
});
```

Comment: I need to add I'm using an Ajax call to load my Ember application and test code. After checking on a new install, it works properly when putting everything in the head, but when fetching it with Ajax despite loading and starting QUnit manually when everything is loaded this error happens.

Comment: So is it allowed to load Ember using jQuery getScript ?

Comment: What's advanceReadiness?

Comment: And do you have a route defined that lives at the root, if so, what's the associated route/controller/model look like?

Comment: According to Ember website : _"By default, calling Ember.Application.create() will automatically initialize your application by calling the Ember.Application.initialize() method. If you need to delay initialization, you can call your app's deferReadiness() method. When you are ready for your app to be initialized, call its advanceReadiness() method."_

Comment: I inserted the route code in the question for better formatting (as stack's comment formatting is pretty limited).

Answer (score 0):

You should go read http://emberjs.com/guides/testing/integration/

With the newest Ember you don't need to run `App.advanceReadiness`, only the `App.reset` in the `teardown`, and before defining any test suite, you need to call:

```
App.rootElement = '#qunit-fixtures';
App.setupForTesting();
App.injectTestHelpers();
```

And all should work fine.

Lemme know if following this is not working, and if so give a jsbin I could work on ;-)

**EDIT**

Also I'm not sure that would change anything but in their exemples they're using `andThen` instead of `then`:

```
visit('/');
andThen(function(){ ... });
```